# Show $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})\cong \mathbb{\mathbb{Z_2\times Z_2}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $ f(x) = x^4 −4 ∈ \mathbb{Q}[x],$ find the splitting field $E$ of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, then show that $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})\cong \mathbb{\mathbb{Z_2\times Z_2}}$

---

the roots of $f$ are $\sqrt2,-\sqrt2,i\sqrt2,-i\sqrt2$ so the spliting field $E=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,i\sqrt2)$

the elements of  $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})$ are:

$σ_0=id, σ_1(\sqrt2)=-\sqrt2, σ_2(i\sqrt2)=-i\sqrt2$ , but these are $3$ elements how it's possible $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})\cong \mathbb{\mathbb{Z_2\times Z_2}}$?

Where is my mistake?

Edit after koljas comment, it should be $σ_0=id, σ_1:\sqrt2\rightarrow -\sqrt2 \:\text{and}\: i\sqrt2\rightarrow i\sqrt2, σ_2: \sqrt2\rightarrow \sqrt2 \:\text{and}\: i\sqrt2\rightarrow -i\sqrt2 , σ_3: \sqrt2\rightarrow -\sqrt2 \:\text{and}\: i\sqrt2\rightarrow -i\sqrt2 $

Comment: What is $\sigma_1(i)$? What is $\sigma_2(\sqrt2)$?

Comment: You defined $\sigma_i$ only on one element. You need to define it on the whole field. So for example define it on both $\sqrt{2}$ and $i\sqrt{2}$, or find a basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i\sqrt{2})$, and define them on a linear basis of said field.

Comment: @Arthur the automorphisms of $Gal(E/Q)$ that sends every element to itself except of those $2$

Comment: @Kolja ohh i think I get what you mean.

Comment: @Kolja I edited my question according to your comment , for the isomorphism I thought to consider $σ\rightarrow (sgn(σ,)sgn(σ))$ , or use the theorem that states that $G\cong H\times N$ where $HN=G$ etc.

Comment: I think it's pretty obvious at this point. There are four elements, all different, all of order two, so it must be $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$.

Comment: @Kolja I agree, but shouldn't I state explicit which is that isomorphism ?

Comment: You can if you wish. There are multiple isomorphisms, for example, you can permute $\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \sigma_3$ however you wish, and just send them to $(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)$. Another option, which is probably what you wanted to say, is to send $\sigma_j$ to $\left(\log_{-1}\left(\frac{\sigma_j(\sqrt{2})}{\sqrt{2}}\right),\log_{-1}\left(\frac{\sigma_j(i\sqrt{2})}{i\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$ . Here I use the map $\log_{-1}$ which sends $-1 \mapsto 1$ and $1 \mapsto 0$.

Comment: @Kolja thanks so much!, didn't understand the second isomorphism, but thats ok I will study it to understand it.

Comment: You're welcome. Just evaluate the function at some of the $\sigma_j$ and you will understand what it's about.

Comment: "the automorphisms of $Gal(E/\Bbb Q)$ that sends every element to itself except of those $2$" What? Even if we say $\sigma_1(i)=i$, then we still have, for instance, $\sigma_1(1+3\sqrt2-5i-2i\sqrt2)=1-3\sqrt2-5i+2i\sqrt2$. _Many_ elements aren't sent to themselves by $\sigma_1$.

Comment: @Arthur ohh ok you are right , I didn't phrase that correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to give a thourough explanation of what is going on. Our goal ist to understand $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})$ where $E$ is the splitting field of $X^4-4\in \mathbb{Q}[X]$. Clearly in $\mathbb{C}[X]$ this polynomial factors $(X^2-2)(X^2+2)=(X-\sqrt{2})(X+\sqrt{2})(X+i\sqrt{2})(X-i\sqrt{2})$ and the splitting field is thus genereated by the roots of this polynomial, hence $E=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i\sqrt{2})$. We know that $\#Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})=[E:\mathbb{Q}]=4$, because we have $[E:\mathbb{Q}]=[E:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=2\cdot 2=4$.

Consider the canonical embedding $\sigma:\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ by a standard theorem we know that for every root of $X^2-2$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ we get a continuation of $\sigma$ that send $\sqrt{2}$ to the root. Let $\sigma':\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\to \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\hookrightarrow E$ be the canonical continuation of such a continuation to $E$ by inclusion. Apllying the same argument again we obtain the four elements of the galois group:
$$ \sigma_1=\operatorname{id}_E; \ \sigma_2:\sqrt{2}\to -\sqrt{2},i\sqrt{2}\to i\sqrt{2};\ \sigma_3:\sqrt{2}\to \sqrt{2},i\sqrt{2}\to -i\sqrt{2}; \ \sigma_4:\sqrt{2}\to -\sqrt{2},i\sqrt{2}\to -i\sqrt{2}$$
In particular we know that $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})$ is $\cong \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ or $\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. In order to find out which of those is the case we look at the order of the elements in $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})$, but one easily sees that no element has order $4$. Hence, $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.